# Coloring question

Tags: theming

Is there a way that every time the word green appears, anywhere on my website, that the font shade is the color green?  Is there a module that would help, or something in css or scss?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated based on comment**

A simple jQuery solution might be ideal here.

In your theme.info add a reference to jquery.highlight.js, custom.js and custom.css files:

```
name = My theme
description = Theme developed by me.
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate
scripts[] = jquery.highlight.js
scripts[] = custom.js
stylesheets[all][] = custom.css
```

Or you can use drupal_add_js() and module or theme, see https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

Rather than using "Highlight Keywords on a Page with Jquery" found at http://hawkee.com/snippet/9854/, let's use a fork of the JQuery Highlight Plugin by Penagwin found at http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html to more efficiently handle multiple colors.

Save this file to your theme as jquery.highlight.js from the source at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18269294/penagwinhighlight.js

jquery.highlight.js contains:

```
/*

highlight v4m1

Highlights arbitrary terms.

<http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html>

MIT license.

Modified by Penagwin to allow custom css classes.
<dev.penagw.in>

Johann Burkard
<http://johannburkard.de>
<mailto:jb@eaio.com>

*/

jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat, classn) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
  var skip = 0;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
   if (pos >= 0) {
    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
    spannode.className = String(classn);
    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
    skip = 1;
   }
  }
  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
   }
  }
  return skip;
 }
 return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
 }) : this;
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
 return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
  this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
  with (this.parentNode) {
   replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
   normalize();
  }
 }).end();
};
```

Then in custom.js add the following:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".field-name-body").highlight("green", "green");
    $(".field-name-body").highlight("red", "red");
    $(".field-name-body").highlight("blue", "blue");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And custom.css:

```
.red{ 
  color: #ED3027;
}
.green { 
  color: #497206;
}
.blue{ 
  color: #0864A6;
}
```

Clear cache and and the color names found inside a `.field-name-body` class will be colored.  Change the element name to what best matches your theme structure.  For example `article` or `#content` may be more appropriate.  Obviously for your use case the jquery.highlight.js function could be optimized to use the pattern as the highlight classname, but this gives you more freedom in naming classes.

Comment: I am also looking to expand this to making red "red" and blue "blue".

Comment: Updated answer to reflect need for multiple colors.